# Using the Bolzano's theorem to prove that exists only one solution in the interval.

Tags: calculus

Considering the Bolzano's theorem: *Let $f$ be continuous at each point of a closed interval $[a, b]$ and assume that $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ have opposite signs. Then there is **at least one** $c$ in the open interval $(a, b)$ such that $f(c) = 0$.*

How can I use the Bolzano's theorem to prove that exists **only one** solution?

For example:

$f(x) = 25 + 60 e^{-0.35x}$

how can I prove that exists **only one** solution for $f(x)=40$ in the interval  $x \in ]3,4[$ ?

Comment: Do you mean using a combination of Bolzano's theorem and Rolle's theorem?

Comment: Only with Bolzano's theorem. I found the solution in the first answer: i need to prove that f is strictly monotonically decreasing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the function $f$ is in addition strictly monotonically increasing (or decreasing as your example), then there is exactly one solution.

The Bolzano theorem alone cannot help to prove uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

Check the signs of f(x)-40 at the endpoints of that interval to conclude they are different from each other. Then notice that f(x) is strictly decreasing (f'(x)<0)
as the part e^-c*x is strictly decreasing and the constant doesn't affect this. Combine these two bits of information to conclude that only one solution exists.